# Move a string to a header element from child only if the string exists in all the child elements using XSLT

Tags: xslt

My XML code & XSLT code
explanation :
I'm trying to move the string '2' from the elements with

```
(tr[@type='detail'] and td[@column='1'])
```

to the category header

```
(tr [@type='categoryhead' and level='2'])
```

Any help on this is greatly appreciated
Thanks a ton

```
<!--=============My XML=============-->
<tbody xmlns="http://mynamespace.com">
  <tr layoutcode="" type="categoryhead" level="1" categorykey="2789" hierarchykey="4921">
    <td colname="1">Bonds</td>
  </tr>
  <tr layoutcode="" type="categoryhead" level="2" categorykey="3255" hierarchykey="4922">
    <td colname="1">Beverages</td>
  </tr>
  <tr layoutcode="" type="detail" level="3" securitymasterkey="41164">
    <td colname="1">Security_1(1,2)</td>
    <td colname="2">500</td>`enter code here`
    <td colname="3">330</td>
  </tr>
  <tr layoutcode="" type="detail" level="3" securitymasterkey="41167">
    <td colname="1">Security_4(1,2,3,4)</td>
    <td colname="2">10</td>
    <td colname="3">265</td>
  </tr>
  <tr layoutcode="" type="categorytotal" level="2" categorykey="3255" hierarchykey="4922">
    <td colname="1">Beverages</td>
    <td colname="2">530</td>
    <td colname="3">1,045</td>
  </tr>
  <tr layoutcode="" type="categorytotal" level="1" categorykey="2789" hierarchykey="4921">
    <td colname="1">TOTAL Bonds</td>
    <td colname="2">530</td>
    <td colname="3">1,045</td>
  </tr>

  <tr layoutcode="" type="categoryhead" level="1" categorykey="2936" hierarchykey="4921">
    <td colname="1">Options</td>
  </tr>
  <tr layoutcode="" type="categoryhead" level="2" categorykey="3248" hierarchykey="4922">
    <td colname="1">Agriculture</td>
  </tr>
  <tr layoutcode="" type="detail" level="3" securitymasterkey="41168">
    <td colname="1">Security_5(@,1)</td>
    <td colname="2">10</td>
    <td colname="3">890</td>
  </tr>
  <tr layoutcode="" type="detail" level="3" securitymasterkey="41168">
    <td colname="1">Security_5(@,2)</td>
    <td colname="2">10</td>
    <td colname="3">890</td>
  </tr>
  <tr layoutcode="" type="categorytotal" level="2" categorykey="3248" hierarchykey="4922">
    <td colname="1">Agriculture</td>
    <td colname="2">10</td>
    <td colname="3">890</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

XSLT where I'm trying to move the string '2' from the elements with (tr[@type='detail'] and td[@column='1'])to the category header (tr [@type='categoryhead' and level='2'])

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:a="http://mynamespace.com" version="2.0">

  <!-- Global Variable -->
  <xsl:variable name="arg1" select="'2'"></xsl:variable>

  <!-- This identity template copies the document -->
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @* "/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="a:tbody/a:tr[@type='categoryhead' and @level='2']/a:td">
    <xsl:for-each select="//a:tbody/a:tr[@type='detail']/a:td[@colname='1'][contains(.,$arg1)]">
      <xsl:variable name="IsFooted" select="contains(.,$arg1)"></xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="count(//a:tbody/a:tr[@type='detail']/a:td[@colname='1'][contains(.,$arg1)])"/>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$IsFooted='true'">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('(',concat($arg1,')'))"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Desired XML Output:

```
<tbody xmlns="http://mynamespace.com">
  <tr layoutcode="" type="categoryhead" level="1" categorykey="2789" hierarchykey="4921">
    <td colname="1">Bonds</td>
  </tr>
  <tr layoutcode="" type="categoryhead" level="2" categorykey="3255" hierarchykey="4922">
    <td colname="1">Beverages (2)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr layoutcode="" type="detail" level="3" securitymasterkey="41164">
    <td colname="1">Security_1(1)</td>
    <td colname="2">500</td>
    <td colname="3">330</td>
  </tr>
  <tr layoutcode="" type="detail" level="3" securitymasterkey="41167">
    <td colname="1">Security_4(1,3,4)</td>
    <td colname="2">10</td>
    <td colname="3">265</td>
  </tr>
  <tr layoutcode="" type="categorytotal" level="2" categorykey="3255" hierarchykey="4922">
    <td colname="1">Beverages</td>
    <td colname="2">530</td>
    <td colname="3">1,045</td>
  </tr>
  <tr layoutcode="" type="categorytotal" level="1" categorykey="2789" hierarchykey="4921">
    <td colname="1">TOTAL Bonds</td>
    <td colname="2">530</td>
    <td colname="3">1,045</td>
  </tr>

  <tr layoutcode="" type="categoryhead" level="1" categorykey="2936" hierarchykey="4921">
    <td colname="1">Options</td>
  </tr>
  <tr layoutcode="" type="categoryhead" level="2" categorykey="3248" hierarchykey="4922">
    <td colname="1">Agriculture</td>
  </tr>
  <tr layoutcode="" type="detail" level="3" securitymasterkey="41168">
    <td colname="1">Security_5(@,1)</td>
    <td colname="2">10</td>
    <td colname="3">890</td>
  </tr>
  <tr layoutcode="" type="detail" level="3" securitymasterkey="41168">
    <td colname="1">Security_5(@,2)</td>
    <td colname="2">10</td>
    <td colname="3">890</td>
  </tr>
  <tr layoutcode="" type="categorytotal" level="2" categorykey="3248" hierarchykey="4922">
    <td colname="1">Agriculture</td>
    <td colname="2">10</td>
    <td colname="3">890</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: It isn't at all clear what you want to do.  `(tr[@type='detail'] and td[@column='1'])` but there are no `td` elements with attribute `column`.  Assuming `@column` is a typo for `@colname`, where is the string `2` you want to move?

Comment: The only noted differences are adding "Beverages (2)" and removing the words "enter code here" from the source and the desired XML. I cannot understand the question either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The terminology is not quite clear here, as looking at the output sample, all that is happening is a "(2)" is being appended to a particular table cell, so it is not really moving anything.

Also, your question title of the question mentions about child elements, but looking at the XML structure, the "detail" rows are actually siblings of the "categoryhead" rows. This is probably where the problem lies; how do you correlate the "detail" rows with the associated "categoryheader". One way to do this could be using a key

```
<xsl:key name="row" 
         match="a:tr[@level != '1']" 
         use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::a:tr[@level=current()/@level - 1][1])" />
```

This gets the rows (other than at level 1) and groups them by the first preceding row with a lowel @level attribute.

Now, for your template match, because you are changing "td" elements, I would change the template to match such an element, rather than the "tr" element

```
 <xsl:template match="a:tbody/a:tr[@type='categoryhead' and @level='2']/a:td[@colname='1']">
```

You can then use the key to get the 'child' elements, but instead of thinking in terms of if all child elements contain a '2', reverse the logic and check whether any child eleent doesn't contain a '2'

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:a="http://composition.bowne.com/2010/v4" version="1.0">

  <!-- Global Variable -->
  <xsl:variable name="arg1" select="'2'"></xsl:variable>

  <xsl:key name="row" match="a:tr[@level != '1']" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::a:tr[@level=current()/@level - 1][1])" />

  <!-- This identity template copies the document -->
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="a:tbody/a:tr[@type='categoryhead' and @level='2']/a:td[@colname='1']">
      <xsl:variable name="IsMissing" select="key('row', generate-id(..))/a:td[@colname='1'][not(contains(text(), $arg1))]" />
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not($IsMissing)">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('(',concat($arg1,')'))"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As an aside, the namespace in your XSLT does not match the namespace in your XML. You would need these to match for this to work, but I assume this is a typo.

EDIT: To remove the '2' from the 'detail' rows, try adding the following template. The 'isMissing' variable is a bit messier, because it has to find the associated 'categoryhead' first. Also note it uses 'replace' which is only available in XSLT 2.0.

```
  <xsl:template match="a:tbody/a:tr[@type='detail']/a:td[@colname='1']">
    <xsl:variable name="parentLevel" select="../@level - 1" />
    <xsl:variable name="IsMissing" select="key('row', generate-id(../preceding-sibling::a:tr[@level=$parentLevel][1]))/a:td[@colname='1'][not(contains(text(), $arg1))]" />
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not($IsMissing)">
          <xsl:value-of select="replace(., concat(',', $arg1), '')"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Your code worked like a magic!! and i could append the string to the header. is there any way we can remove the string ('2' as per xml) when we append the text to header

Comment: Do you mean "Security_1(1,2)" would become "Security_1(1)"? As you are using XSLT 2.0, this is much easier than in XSLT 1.0, but perhaps you can edit your desired XML to show it with the 2 removed? Thanks!

Comment: I Edited the desired xml out

Comment: The replace part works but not fully: works when scenario1 :Security_1(1,2), Security_1(1,2,3) and so on --> this works perfectly. But it does not work when Scenario2: Security_1(1), Security_1(1,2) --> in the out xml Im expecting the '2' should not get replaced for scenario2.   Any thoughts   thanks a ton.

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake in my template with regards checking the @level attribute, which I have hopefully now corrected